# C# - using TableAdapter to return a single value from stored procedure returns null

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, tableadapter

I do not understand but my stored procedure which I added to table adapter only returns null value. It is supposed to return a simple integer value. In the preview I had with data set desinger, I could clearly get the integer value that I wanted. But for some reason I cannot get the value from my codes.

I followed the instruction of MSDN library:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37hwc7kt(VS.80).aspx

My code for c# is:

```
humansDataSetTableAdapters.ProfilesTableAdapter tableAdapter 
= new humansDataSetTableAdapters.ProfilesTableAdapter(); 

int returnValue = (int)tableAdapter.getSample();

Console.Write(returnValue);
```

My code for stored procedure getSample is:

```
DECLARE @r int
SET @r = 7
RETURN @r
```

Can anybody let me know how I can solve this problem??
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalar expects a result, not a return. Be definition, it looks for the first column, first row.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Try

```
DECLARE @r int
SET @r = 7
SELECT @r
```

Answer (score 1):

rather than going for this solution I would like to suggest you to use `ExecuteScalar` if stored procedure returning single value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Comment: Thanks for help, but I still want to solve the problem using tableAdapter!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a typed DataSet? If so, make sure your Stored Procedure is set to return a Scalar value.

Comment: I am using a defualt DataSet. In my DataSet designer, I can see that the ExecuteMode of getSample() stored procedure is set to Scalar.

Comment: Humm.. then I suspect the issue is with your SP. Can you update your post with a sample of the SP?

Comment: It is confusing that I can actually see the value 7 in my DataSet preview.