# Use Stored procedures that uses the "EXECUTE" command in a TableAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am writing a program that needs to call a MSSQL stored procedure called *dbo.getsystemnumber*; this procedure generates the next pyd_number which I need to insert a new line in the paydetail table. This is what the procedure looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getsystemnumber](@p_controlid varchar(8), @p_alternateid varchar(8)) 
AS
    DECLARE @return_number int
    EXECUTE @return_number = dbo.getsystemnumber_gateway @p_controlid, @p_alternateid, 1
    RETURN @return_number
```

I'm using the c# tableadapter to call this procedure but when I do call it and say put it on a label or listbox, it just returns a value of 0. The function still updates in SQL server to the next number when I run the program.

```
TMW_Test2DataSetTableAdapters.paydetailTableAdapter returnPydNumber = new TMW_Test2DataSetTableAdapters.paydetailTableAdapter();
lbPydnumber.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(returnPydNumber.getsystemnumber("PYDNUM", " ")));
```

However, when I use the preview data option in the tableadapter view I get the right number that I'm supposed to get. In SQL Server we call it like this:

```
declare @pyd_number int
execute @pyd_number = dbo.getsystemnumber N'PYDNUM', NULL
select @pyd_number
```

Comment: The two methods of calling are not the same, because one supplies NULL and the other a space. Investigate the behaviour in both cases.

Comment: Please don't include tags in the question's title, @AliAzam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - using TableAdapter to return a single value from stored procedure returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409904/c-sharp-using-tableadapter-to-return-a-single-value-from-stored-procedure-retu)

Comment: @UweKeim can you please tell me why you sent me this type of message?

Comment: @AliAzam it is discouraged to put tags into titles as it look messy and can make the question unclear. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles and "Should I use tags in titles?" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: Why are you using TableAdapter? Thats not the right tool even if you make it work. Use ExecuteScalar and please [read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706361/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @Rhumborl I didn't post this question or include tags in the question's title. So why the message to me?

Comment: the first command in any stored proc should be `set nocount on`

Answer (score 0):

`TableAdapter`s use the result of a `SELECT` statement for their data, not the `RETURN` value of a query. Under the hood, a single value TableAdapter will use `ExecuteScalar()`, which takes the first column in the first row of the resultset.

[This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2006/08/09/how-to-retrieve-stored-procedure-return-values-from-tableadapter/) explains this and a workaround. Either change the store procedure to `SELECT` the value instead of `RETURN`ing it, or change the generated code to look at the ReturnValue of the database call.